# How can I correctly tie in this equation with a GUI for this finals grade calculator?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a finals grade calculator using python. I am using Tkinter for the GUI. I have created an equation which calculates your grade after finals.
*(Desired Grade - (Current grade * 1 - grade weight) / Grade weight*.

However, I am getting a "float division by zero" error when I click to get my results after entering my numbers into the entry boxes. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

NOTE: "Grade Weight" is a percentage decimal which is why I use float on *GradeBox2*

```
from tkinter import *

main = Tk()

# --- VARS ---
GradeBox1 = tkinter.IntVar()
GradeBox2 = tkinter.IntVar()
GradeBox3 = tkinter.IntVar()

# --- FUNCTION ---


def program():
    try:
        print(float(GradeBox3.get())) - (GradeBox1.get() * (1 - float(GradeBox2.get()))) / (float(
            GradeBox2.get()))

    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        'error'

# --- MAIN ---


Label(main, text="Current Grade").grid(row=0)
Entry(main, textvariable=GradeBox1).grid(row=0, column=1)

Label(main, text='Weight of exam (Enter decimal then percentage ex: .30)').grid(row=2)
Entry(main, textvariable=GradeBox2).grid(row=2, column=1)

Label(main, text='Desired grade').grid(row=4)
Entry(main, textvariable=GradeBox3).grid(row=4, column=1)

mybutton = Button(main, text='Get your grade!', command=program).grid(row=6, column=0)

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Break the computation into small pieces and then examine each piece to see if it’s what you think it should be.

Comment: ```print((GradeBox3.get()-(GradeBox1.get()*1-GradeBox2.get()))/GradeBox2.get())```?

Comment: I believe it is definitely an error with the function. I cannot figure out why it receives zero though. My guess is that maybe its a problem with the grade percentage and how that translates.

Comment: ```GradeBox2``` should not be ```0``` because you are dividing it. This will raise a ```ZeroDivisionError```

Comment: Just add a fairly small number to the denominator (0.00001) to prevent zero division, regardless of the values of the fields that are applied to the denominator in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you expect `GradeBox3`'s value to be between 0 and 1. If so, the problem is that you're passing an `IntVar` to the `Entry` object, causing your input value to be cast to an integer, as casting a float to an int gives you the [floor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) of the value passed. In your case that would change floating point values above 0 and below 1 to a 0, causing a division by zero error later. Your (float) cast does nothing significant because the value have there is already 0 by that point. Using `DoubleVar`s instead of `IntVar`s should solve your problem.

Comment: It does fix the division error! However, I get the ```unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'float'``` error. But there shouldnt be any reason you cant subtract floats right? I would think it would be a 'nonetype" error, but I couldnt see the reason for that.

Comment: @Caden, try ```print((GradeBox3.get()-(GradeBox1.get()*1-GradeBox2.get()))/GradeBox2.get())```

Comment: @sujay, thank you! This wasnt it, however I found a solution thanks to this. It was actually ```((GradeBox3.get() - (GradeBox1.get() * (1 - GradeBox2.get()))) / GradeBox2.get())``` to get the correct calculations! And thank you to @nradk as that solution also helped to get rid of the errors.